# Remove default padding from Ant design table

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

https://ant.design/components/table/

- I want to remove the default padding and margin from the ant design table.
- I put the small size table but it is not enough, I still see that there is an extra 16px margin and padding which I want to remove.
- Problem is when I call the classes and reset the margin, It does not work, what could be the reason for this?

I am using ant design 4.17 and react v17

[image: screenshot of the class I am trying to modify]

This is what I tried but it does not work.

```
.ant-table-tbody{
  padding: 0;
}
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td{
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be found these className in the node_modules folder. node_modules/antd/es. Then, you found the index.css file lists out all of the classNames and attributes that are editable.
or
you can be use

```css
.ant-table-tbody{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```